# Why alt+/ doesn't work in the ADT

Tags: android, adt

All, Forgive me I am a newbie for the Android world, I have a problem with the preference of IDE(ADT), Because The content assist short cut (alt+/) doesn't work for me. Please help to review it .thanks.

In the following code, I hope content assist can automatically make suggestions for me ,But it does't  show anything when I press `Alt+/`. So far what I can do is right-click mouse, and select `source\Override/implement methods..`. But I think it still seems verbose for overriding method. Is there any better way to make it? thanks.

[image]

[image]

Comment: I thought the default shortcut for content assist in Eclipse was Ctrl+Space

Comment: @AleksG Unfortunately ctrl+space is used by IME. and I already changed to alt+/. As you can see the above. thanks.

Comment: I think the issue may be with the `Alt` modifier.  Have you tried to get it to be Ctrl-something?